# Test if a string contains at least 2 words in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have an sql request like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE lower(title) LIKE lower('%It's a beautiful string i think%')
```

I need to check if at least 2 words in my string `It's a beautiful string i think` are contained in my field title... How can i do that ?

For example, if in my field title i have the string `I think it's beautiful`, This query should return me this object...

Thanks !

Comment: So rows that have `'i a'` should be returned as well, right?

Comment: You could check for the existence of two spaces: `LIKE ('_% _% %')`.

Comment: Yes for 'i a'.. maybe check before if the word contain more of 2 characters

Comment: @xbonez OP does not want *any* two words, only two words from his sentence.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Oh...I think it's time for me to go to bed.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud I suppose you have to write a function to split your input sentence and check each word if it exists in the main sentence, increasing some counter value

Comment: I think you'll have to build a query with 30 conditions, listing all possible pairs in both orders, like this: `where lower(title) like `%it's%a%` OR lower(title) like `%a%it's%` OR lower(title) like `%it's%beautiful%` OR lower(title) like `%beautiful%it's%` OR ...` and so on for all 6*5 combinations.

Comment: How about `WHERE (LENGTH(title) - LENGTH(REPLACE(title, ' ', ''))) > 2` what I am doing here is removing the spaces then deduce from the total length of title the result and if bigger than 2 that's it or any number u want.

Answer (score 2):

You could split your string into a temporary table (say, using something like this: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/) and then do a join, with a count.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the following SQL statement dynamically:

```
SELECT title, count(*)
FROM 
   (
    SELECT title 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (' ' + lower(title) + ' ') LIKE lower('% It %')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (' ' + lower(title) + ' ') LIKE lower('% s %')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (' ' + lower(title) + ' ') LIKE lower('% a %')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (' ' + lower(title) + ' ') LIKE lower('% beautiful %')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (' ' + lower(title) + ' ') LIKE lower('% string %')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (' ' + lower(title) + ' ') LIKE lower('% I %')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (' ' + lower(title) + ' ') LIKE lower('% think %')
    ) AS table2
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

A stored procedure might be more efficient and you could have the whole job done on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckSentece] (@mainSentence varchar(128), @checkSentence varchar(128))
RETURNS NUMERIC AS
BEGIN
  SET @mainSentence=LOWER(@mainSentence)
  SET @checkSentence=LOWER(@checkSentence)
  DECLARE @pos INT
  DECLARE @word varchar(32)
  DECLARE @count NUMERIC
  SET @count=0
  WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @checkSentence) > 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(' ', @checkSentence)  
    SELECT @word = SUBSTRING(@checkSentence, 1, @pos-1)      
    DECLARE @LEN NUMERIC

    //Simple containment check, better to use another charindex loop to check each word from @mainSentence
    SET @LEN=(SELECT LEN(REPLACE(@mainSentence,@word,'')))
    if (@LEN<LEN(@mainSentence)) SET @count=@count+1     
    SELECT @checkSentence = SUBSTRING(@checkSentence, @pos+1, LEN(@checkSentence)-@pos)
  END
  return @count
END
```

and get the number of words from second sentence contained in the first one